# page redirection is not working in visualforce page

Tags: apex, controller

here when i will give any jobid which is available in interview object then after pressing the enter button 1 new page(Feedback_JobID) will open and if the jobid is not available inside the interview object then 1 error message will come. But whenever i am trying to do that here for every value it is showing the error message can anybody give me the idea what is wrong here..

VF PAGE

```
<apex:page controller="Client_Feedback" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="true">
<apex:Pagemessages id="msg"/>
<apex:form >
<CENTER><apex:image url="{!$Resource.LOGO}" width="200" height="130"/></CENTER>
<CENTER><p><b>Client Login Page</b><br /></p></CENTER>
<CENTER>
<apex:panelGrid columns="3" style="margin-top:1em;">
<p><b>JOB ID:</b><br />
<apex:inputText required="true" id="ID" value="{!var}"/>

<apex:commandButton action="{!search}" value="enter" id="enter"/>
  </p> 
</apex:panelGrid>
</CENTER>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

CONTROLLER

```
public class Client_Feedback {       
    public String ID {get;set;}
    public string var{set;get;}
    public List < SCSCHAMPS__Interview__c > intList {get;set;}
    //public Freelancer__c fre {get;set;}
    public PageReference search()
     {
        {

            //this.intList.clear();
            List<SCSCHAMPS__Interview__c> intList = [SELECT id,SCSCHAMPS__Job__c
                                                 FROM SCSCHAMPS__Interview__c
                                                 WHERE SCSCHAMPS__Job__c= :var  limit 1 ];
             pageReference ref; 

             if(intList!= null)
             {

                 ref= page.Feedback_JobID;
                ref.setRedirect(true);
                return ref;

             }
             else {

               ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'TRY AGAIN... .'));

            }
            return ref ;

             }                                              
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to move `return null;` code inside else block

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using Id variable

```
List<SCSCHAMPS__Interview__c> intList = [SELECT id,SCSCHAMPS__Job__c
                                                     FROM SCSCHAMPS__Interview__c 
                                                     WHERE SCSCHAMPS__Job__c= :ID  limit 1 ];
```

and on VF page you are using `var` to get input

```
<apex:inputText required="true" id="ID" value="{!var}"/>
```

Use same variable in both place.

Also you have one extra set of curly bracket in Search method.

Comment: thank u but i dont think extra curly bracket should be a problem and about the comparison we should compare id's right?correct me if i am wrong. but i tried doing wat you said still the result is same @Tushar

Comment: @prinks check if Both are same length either 15 or 18. Also I can't see the code where you comparing. So are you sure you are passing correct id and you have records in system.

Comment: yes records are there @tushar

Comment: @prinks did you face the variable issue. Share your updated code.

Comment: i have updated the code i just replaced isempty() with not equal to null so that its is redirecting to the next page but for any input it is redirecting whether it is available in the database or not.so confused... @tushar

Comment: @prinks check ` intList.size > 0` also I think you need to pass Id or some other parameter in second page.